# API se puede enviar archivos PDF binarios a través de la API de WhatsApp de Infobip

Tags: c#, postman

tengo una duda respecto al envio de documentacion por API se puede enviar archivos PDF binarios a través de la API de WhatsApp de Infobip es decir pdf b64 consumiento API ?

Mire la documentación de Infobip para saber si se puede y no he encontrado nada al respecto

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.